# draw, pull, drag... what’s the proper word?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to describe the action of lithely and quickly pulling a satin pillow out of (away from?) underneath someone’s knee pit — This person is sitting in bed and the pillow is placed underneath her leg (the back of her knee, to be percise). It’s silky pillow against smooth skin so it doesn’t take much force to do that.

What word or phrase will possibly best describe it?

How does “draw a pillow out of underneath her knee pit” sound?

Hope someone can give a few examples of their suggestion! Thanks! (:

Comment: Sounds like it's getting "yanked" to me.

Comment: I might go with "slid".

Comment: Knee pit? You mean the back of the knee? "To slip the pillow out from under her knee". A two-word verb followed by a prepositional phrase.

Comment: @Lambie Hi, doesn’t under her knee” sound like she is on her knees and the cushion is placed under her knees? I’m just a bit confused. (:

Comment: “yank” or “jerk”

Comment: You seem to be asking for literary criticism, which isn't allowed here.
If you want to describe the action of lithely and quickly pulling a satin pillow out of (away from?) underneath someone’s knee pit why not do that: why not describe the action then ask whether you described it rightly? 
By the way, although I suspect I understand what you meant there, what’s a *knee-pit*? You’re not suggesting a *knee-pit* is comparable to an *arm-pit*, are you?

Comment: @dethra slip the pillow out from under the back of her knee. Knee pit does not exist.

Comment: **[snatch](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snatch)** the pillow.

Answer (score 1):

You want to say "draw a pillow from underneath her knee." That's it! Lose the words "out" "of" and "pit".

Comment: Thanks! Although I was a bit confused at one thing: I imagine the person is sitting in bed, and the pillow is placed underneath her leg (the back of her knee, percisly). In this case, doesn’t “from underneath her knee” (omitting “pit”) make it sound like the person is on her knee (instead of sitting in bed)? And is knee pit a common word to use? I was using it because I googled... really prefer to hear what a native speaker would say!